# How to exclude a single class from being mapped when using an IAutomappingConfiguration

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using AutoMappings with Fluent NHibernate and would like to exclude a single class from being mapped.  Because I'm using an IAutomappingConfiguration, I apparently cannot use a "Where" clause.  For example, the following can **not** be used in this situation:

```
.Where(t => t != typeof(ClassToExclude))
```

So is there a way to accomplish the exclusion when using an IAutomappingConfiguration?  (As a last resort, I could move the class to a different assembly, but I'm looking for an answer that doesn't require this.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyAutomappingConfiguration : DefaultAutomappingConfiguration
{
    public override bool ShouldMap(Type type)
    {
        return type != typeof(ClassToExclude);
    }
}
```

and use

```
AutoMap.AssemblyOf<SomeEntity>(new MyAutomappingConfiguration())
```

Comment: why the downvote? care to comment whats wrong with the answer?

Comment: You could have put some effort into this answer instead of just copy pasting some code. Like how to configure the DefaultAutomappingConfiguration.

Comment: @gwin003 i wrote this answer specifically for this question. How to use the Automapping configuration is already known to the OP otherwise he wouldnt ask for a solution including it. I could add some words reqphrasing what's in the code but whats the point? For others i will include how to use it